# Exec Stored Procedure with output parameter in Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to refactor code to use `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` instead of `SqlCommand`

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@certificateTypeId", "TA"));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@personId", 1m));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@selfAssessment", xDocument.ToString()));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@selfAssessmentVersion", 1m));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sponsorPersonId", 1m));

var outputParam = new SqlParameter("@certificationEventId", SqlDbType.Decimal, 10);
outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
parameters.Add(outputParam);

string sql = "[My Stored Proc] " + string.Join(" ", parameters.Select(ToEfString).ToArray());

// runtime value: [My Stored Proc] @certificateTypeId @personId @selfAssessment @selfAssessmentVersion @sponsorPersonId @certificationEventId OUT

var result = await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters);

return ((SqlDecimal)outputParam.SqlValue).Value;
```

I'm getting this error:

> SqlException: Incorrect syntax near @personId

What's wrong?

Comment: Try adding comma's in between: `[My Stored Proc] @certificateTypeId, @personId, @...`

Comment: Can you specify the stored procedure parameter names explicitly in the sql call?

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @PeterB: thanks, that was it. I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add comma's in between the parameters:

```
[My Stored Proc] @certificateTypeId, @personId, @...
```